# Limit admin rights requested by Exchange Active Sync mail account on mobile phone

Tags: mobile, exchange

**Background**:

Setting up an organisational Exchange mail account on a private mobile phone (Android) using Active Sync, one has to accept quite extensive administrative rights for the Exchange mail server, including not only wiping the organisational account with all mails, contacts and calendars (which seems legitimate, as the organisation has an interest to prevent leaking data, even if sending sensitive data by mail is forbiden anyway), but even the right to wipe/reset the whole phone, i.e. also all private contacts, photos etc. on a private, self-paid device. The organisation wants users to respond on the weekend on private equipment, and all are more than happy to do so (but have problems with the extended admin rights and are not willing to carry two separate private/work devices all the time), but this is not part of the discussion.

All agree that wiping the whole phone may be a valuable offer *if* one trusts the Exchange server, the people operating it, and assumes that never ever a malicious attack will affect the mail server and not only destroy the account but proceed to user phones... And there may be reasons to limit this trust, but this is not part of the question.

**Question part 1:**

Enforcement of this policy seems to depend on the device and mail client, at least - in contrast to the stock mail client - Outlook did not ask for permission (but may have a bias not to "confuse" customers" and use them nevertheless?). **Is there a way to confirm (Android itself, Samsung mail app, Outlook), which administrative rights have actually been set**, or what was just an information that does not actually apply, or what rights have been taken w/o asking?

**Question part 2 (main part):**

If there are indeed differences in actually applying adminstrative rights, there seems the **possibility to limit them**, e.g. to the mail etc. account in qustion. How to (beyond using IMAP instead of Active Sync on Exchange server)?

**Question part 3:**

Is there any **documantation, what exact admin rights this includes, and any experience, how they are usually applied?** I.e. if they are (by default/usually) automated, if/what time frame there is for potential intervention (e.g.. show the IT departmant that one still possesses the phone but was just too stupid to unlock the screen correctly too often) or depend on manual review (call client by landline and confirm phone is no longer under his control)? I am asking here because the IT department denies the administrative rights and is not aware of the problem at all, even though the mail client asks for it.

*In summary, I am concerned that this intended security "feature" (protect organisational data, legitimately intended) also implies a significant security risk (private data - I am more concerned to lose my data by Exchange server policy then someone else seeing my holiday fotos), so I am looking to improve security by means in addition of regular backups.*